# Yii2 :: Как обновить существующий список enum?

Tags: mysql, yii2, enum

Есть в базе список enum ('name_1','name_2','name_3'). Был создан контроллер и модель, все работает отлично.

Позже я изменил список на ('new_name_1','new_name_2','new_name_3'), но в форме для ввода данных я все еще вижу старый список ('name_1','name_2','name_3'), соответственно при попытке сохранить выскакивает ошибка, т.к. идет несоответствие с базой.

**Подскажите, можно ли изменить где-то список enum?** Я так понимаю он где-то был зафиксирован при создании модели или контроллера.

Спасибо.

Comment: Если вы создавали модель ActiveRecord через gii, посмотрите в ней.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем нужно было кроме БД еще в форме поменять...

Answer (score 0):

Нужно в модели поменять атрибуты `name_1,name_2,name_3` на `new_name_1, new_name_2, new_name_3`